# Getting rsyslog to write remote logs to a specific file based on the port

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I am setting up a simple rsyslog server for 4 different application logs. What I would like to achieve is that each application will send logs to a specific port and it will be written to a specific file:

- application 1 > tcp syslog port 516 > rsyslog writes to /var/log/application1.log
- application 2 > tcp syslog port 517 > rsyslog writes to /var/log/application2.log

Now I've managed to set up remote logging on the application server, I've set up the imtcp module on rsyslog but I can't make the rulesets work. Here is my /etc/rsyslog.conf configuration

> RULES ####
>
> process remote messages
>
> ruleset(name='remote516'){action(type='omfile'
> file='/var/log/application1.log') stop} input(type='imptcp' port='516'
> ruleset='remote516')
>
> Log all kernel messages to the console. Logging much else clutters up
> the screen.
> #kern.*                                                 /dev/console
>
> local3.error
> /var/log/application1.log
>
> Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher. Don't log private
> authentication messages!
> *.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
>
> The authpriv file has restricted access authpriv.*
> /var/log/secure
>
> Log all the mail messages in one place. mail.*
> -/var/log/maillog

When I try to restart I get these errors:

Apr 12 12:17:45 lgclcbe01 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="13777" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Apr 12 12:17:45 lgclcbe01 kernel: imklog 5.8.10, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Apr 12 12:17:45 lgclcbe01 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="14794" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Apr 12 12:17:45 lgclcbe01 rsyslogd-3000: unknown priority name "log')" [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/3000 ]
Apr 12 12:17:45 lgclcbe01 rsyslogd: the last error occured in /etc/rsyslog.conf, line 38:"ruleset(name='remote516'){action(type='omfile' file='/var/log/application1.log') stop}"
Apr 12 12:17:45 lgclcbe01 rsyslogd: warning: selector line without actions will be discarded
Apr 12 12:17:45 lgclcbe01 rsyslogd-3000: unknown priority name "" [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/3000 ]
Apr 12 12:17:45 lgclcbe01 rsyslogd: the last error occured in /etc/rsyslog.conf, line 39:"input(type='imptcp' port='516' ruleset='remote516')"
Apr 12 12:17:45 lgclcbe01 rsyslogd: warning: selector line without actions will be discarded
Apr 12 12:17:45 lgclcbe01 rsyslogd-2124: CONFIG ERROR: could not interpret master config file '/etc/rsyslog.conf'. [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2124 ]

Since I configured the source to send the logs as local3.error I tried configuring this as a normal rule and it works but since I need to write files based on the port it's not enough. But at least I am sure the problem is in the ruleset and action I'm using.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Have a good day